# Why is ContainsOnly so slow for checking a list is full of zeros?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, expression-test

I'm on Windows 10 Mathematica 12.1.1.

I would expect allocating a big `ConstantArray` and comparing would be slower but apparently it is not:

```
RepeatedTiming[RandomReal[1, 10000] == ConstantArray[0, 10000]]
(* {0.0000589, False} *)
```

```
RepeatedTiming[ContainsOnly[RandomReal[1, 10000], {0}]]
(* {0.00309, False} *)
```

This becomes even worse if I add `SameTest->Equal` which the [documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0btm8ukzwd8g-gz6vvk) states allows some numerical tolerance:

```
RepeatedTiming[ContainsOnly[RandomReal[1, 10000], {0}, SameTest -> Equal]]
(* {7.92, False} *)
```

Why is the above more than ~100,000 times slower than the code that allocates a `ConstantArray` with a large `ByteCount`?! What is going on behind the scenes in `ContainsOnly` that's more expensive than allocation?

Admittedly, in this much bigger case involving sparse arrays `ContainsOnly` is faster, so I'd guess the allocation overhead eventually catches up:

```
RepeatedTiming[SparseArray[999999 -> 1] == ConstantArray[0, 1000000]]
(* {0.00212, False} *)
```

```
RepeatedTiming[ContainsOnly[SparseArray[999999 -> 1, 1000000], {0}]]
(* {0.0000169, False} *)
```

Comment: Look at the timing of `Complement[RandomReal[1, 10000], {0}]`

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks. Complement would have to construct a list though so I'd expect it to be a little slow. ContainsOnly simply has to return True or False.

Comment: I agree that `ContainsOnly` should be able to short circuit and return `False` at the first mismatch, and not continue with the remaining comparisons that `Complement` does.  But it doesn't appear to be implemented that way.

Comment: What @JasonB said. That function is on my to-improve list, though not at the top.